# Redux mapStateToProps returns undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, state, react-redux

Redux is successfully storing and updating state. The reducers are seemingly working correctly. I'm able to use `this.props.dispatch`. However, when it actually comes to detailing that information (i.e. `this.props.array` I always seem to get undefined.

**Reducer:**

```
export default function array(state = {}, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
      case "UPDATE_ARRAY":
        state.array = action.array
        return state;
      default:
        return state;
  }
}
```

**State-aware component:**

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      array: array
    }
  }
```

--

```
  self.props.dispatch({
    type: 'UPDATE_ARRAY',
    array: array
  })
```

--

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
      return {
        messages: state.messages,
        array: state.array
      };
    };

    export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Component);
```

This only seems to be able to save state btw when I define an empty array. This doesn't seem right, I thought the intention of Redux was a self-contained store? Updating a variable seems to defeat the purpose a bit.

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Arent you missing accessing the props object on the constructor: constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      array: props.array
    }
  }

Comment: the default state has no property `array`, so, your component receives `undefined`. Set a default state value or use defaultProps (React Component).

Answer (score 5):

```
export default function array(state = {}, action) {
switch (action.type) {
  case "UPDATE_ARRAY":state={
        ...state,
        array:action.array
                   }
    return state;
  default:
    return state;
```

}
}

- you should always update your state immutably,instead of mutating the current application state ,you should create another object and return that.State should be immutable ,only way to change the state is to create a new one.This helps to improve the performance of the application.
- I am not sure if you application has more than one reducer or not, if it has, than you must be using combine reducer method .So to access state.array in mapsStateToProps is like this

  const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {

  ```
  messages: state.{reducer_name}.message,
  array: state.{reducer_name}.array
  ```

  };
  };
- in place of 'reducer_name' you have to specify the reducers_name which you have define in combine reducer
- And last mapStateToProps return array ,in props not in component state.
  which you can access in this way {this.props.array},you cant set component state in componentDidMount and in componentWillRecieveProps (in case of aysnc action).

Comment: Great explanation. Your answer saved me!!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure the following is your issues, but hope these will help:

```
export default function array(state = {}, {type, array}) {
    switch (type) {
      case "UPDATE_ARRAY":
        return {...state, array};
      default:
        return state;
  }
}
```

Your reducer should be pure, which you had is mutating the state.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      array: array // what is array?
    }
}
```

Above constructor is not right. You should be able to access the `array` from `this.props.array` as your `mapStateToProps`

Do a `console.log(this.props)` in your `render` function or `ComponentWillReceiveProps`, see if you can something :)

Comment: Yes, reducer definitely cannot modify `state` or it won't work. I would suggest not destructuring the action in the function params list as it may confuse readers. Also, it implies that the action payload will always be a variable called 'array', which is not very flexible. So `export default function reducer(state = {}, action) { switch(action.type) { (etc...) return {...state, action.payload }`

Comment: Oops that last bit should end with `return {...state, array: action.payload }` though I would suggest naming it something other than `array`

Answer (score 0):

Your component will receive `array` as a field in its `props` field. Your code assumes it's in the `state` field. So instead of:

```
this.state = {
      array: array
    }
```

you would just access `this.props.array` wherever in your code you need to use the array. You don't need to put it in the local state at all. Usually, you would use it in the `render` function, like in this example:

```
render()
{
  return <div>The array contains {this.props.array.length} items.</div>
}
```

I wonder if you're confusing local state with the Redux store's state? **Local state** is what you get/set when you access `this.state` in your component code.  Every component can have its own state object that it can read from and write to.

The **Redux store's state** is what's passed in to `mapStateToProps`. It's usually the entire state object of all the combined reducers in your top-level reducer (though if you only have one reducer function and are not using `combineReducers`, then the store state is identical to that single reducer's state).

I suggest choosing more descriptive variable names, so that your code will be more readable. It's hard to understand what your intentions are for your code with such generic names. For example, you could name your reducer something that indicates what it's for, like `bookListReducer`, and name the array you want to store and retrieve for what will go inside it, like `books`. Naming both your reducer and all your variables `array` makes it harder to read your code. This will help anyone who reads your code in the future - including, most importantly, you!, as well as future Stack Overflow readers of your future questions (and perhaps this one if you edit it).